# ts2322 - Type ... is not assignable to type ... Object literal may only specify known properties

Tags: typescript

The type definitely has the member explicitly declared. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please give a [mre] **as text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't importing the `CharacterData` type from that other file, so what you're actually using is a built in type provided by typescript which looks like this:

```
/** The CharacterData abstract interface represents a Node object that contains characters. This is an abstract interface, meaning there aren't any object of type CharacterData: it is implemented by other interfaces, like Text, Comment, or ProcessingInstruction which aren't abstract. */
interface CharacterData extends Node, ChildNode, NonDocumentTypeChildNode {
    data: string;
    readonly length: number;
    readonly ownerDocument: Document;
    appendData(data: string): void;
    deleteData(offset: number, count: number): void;
    insertData(offset: number, data: string): void;
    replaceData(offset: number, count: number, data: string): void;
    substringData(offset: number, count: number): string;
}
```

To fix this, export the type in one file, and import it in the other.